# SignalR Core InvokeAsync Freezes

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I had previously been using the SendAsync method to call my SignalR Core hub with no problems.  I realized that if there is an error on the server that I will never know about it from the client with SendAsync, so I decided to use InvokeAsync with the exact same arguments.  When InvokeAsync is called, I can tell that my hub is called and it processes correctly, but the call on the client side ("await InvokeAsync") freezes.  It just locks up and never makes it to the next line of code.  This is a WPF application.  What could be going on?  await SendAsync returns immediately and has never locked up in this way.

Comment: Are you blocking on a task further up in your call stack? I.e., calling `Wait` or `Result`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It turned out it was because the message being sent from the WPF app was also being received by the WPF app, which caused a blocking issue when I tried to update the UI upon receiving a message.  I updated my receive code to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, instead of Dispatcher.Invoke, and now it works.  This was not an issue when I was calling SendAsync from the SignalR client.